# I do not understand this C++ error - error C2101: '&' on constant

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors

This code supposedly works with GCC - I am trying to get it to work with Visual Studio.  I can't figure out if the code is actually faulty or I'm not doing something right with the port.

```
1>c:\somepath\aaa.h(52): error C2101: '&' on constant
1>          c:\somepath\aaa.h(52): while compiling class template member function 'const blahblah::Message something::AClass<Type>::aMethod(void) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=const lala::BClass&
1>          ]
1>          c:\somepath\bbb.h(79) : see reference to class template instantiation 'something:AClass<Type>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=const lala::BClass&
1>          ]
1>  MyApplication.cpp
```

Files

```
aaa.h:52          virtual const Type aMethod() const { return Type(); }

bbb.h:79          AClass<const BClass&> blahblahblah_;
```

Comment: Cute little bug this. I like it.

Comment: Is this a recent version? Seems like VS2010 has reworked this error message.

Comment: Good; it _is_ a bit of a rubbish diagnostic here.

Comment: Hmm, just fired up VS2010, and it's still rather bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constructing `T()` where T is a reference type is not valid, and makes no sense.  Some versions of gcc incorrectly accept it.

Comment: GCC 4.5.1 gets it right, including the error message: http://ideone.com/DOHb3 "error: invalid value-initialization of reference types"